# Bad file descriptor error when implementing piping in C

Tags: c, shell, file-io, pipe, piping

I am trying to implement a sample shell like program which executes the command ls | wc

Using pipes to implement the command. When I execute the command I get the following error.

wc: standard input: Bad file descriptor
0 0 0
wc: -: Bad file descriptor

Please take a look at the code and provide inputs
Note: 1) parse is a library which takes in the input typed and returns each command as a linked list with args and necesary data. Parse is working fine
2) I am executing each command in a different subprocess hence the fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "parse.h"

int pip[3][2];
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
    Pipe p; 
    Cmd c;
    pipe(pip[0]);
    pipe(pip[1]);   
    pid_t pid;
    pid=fork();
    char *host = "armadillo";
    printf("%s%% ", host);
    p = parse();
    c=p->head;  
    printf("1 \n");
    pid=fork();

    if(pid==0)
    {
        close(pip[0][0]);
        close(STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup2(pip[0][1],STDOUT_FILENO);
        execvp(c->args[0],c->args);
    }
    else
    {
        waitpid(pid,NULL,0);
    }
    printf("2 \n");

    close(pip[0][1]);
    close(pip[0][0]);

    c=c->next;
    printf("%s \n",c->args[0]);
    pid=fork();
    if(pid==0)
    {
        close(STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(pip[0][0],STDIN_FILENO);
        close(pip[0][1]);
        execvp(c->args[0],c->args);
    }
    else
    {   
        waitpid(pid,NULL,0);
        close(pip[0][1]);
        close(pip[0][0]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you forking twice? I mean the `fork` Call you do before you actually do anything, why are you doing that?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I am executing each command in a different subprocess
So one fork for ls and other for wc

Comment: Be careful where you close the pipe descriptors.  Also, the processes in a pipeline must all be able to run at once; if you wait for the first to finish before launching the second, you may have it write more data than fits in the pipe, so it blocks waiting for the second process to read from the pipe, but the second process won't be launched until after the first completes, so nothing much happens for a very long time.

Comment: both ends of a pipe must be open at the same time, otherwise writes to the pipe will fail.

Comment: Why are there multiple pipes being opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the lazy way out, and wrote my own rather than fix other code. Treat this as "yet another pipe-fitting example in C", but it might help point out the issues with OP's code.

```
/*
 * hard-wired example program exploring how to implement
 *
 *     system("ls | wc");
 *
 * using calls to pipe(2), fork(2), execvp(2) and wait(2)
 */

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void
do_close(int fd)
{
    if (close(fd) == -1) {
        perror("close");
        exit(1);
    }
}

static void
do_execvp(char *const cmd[])
{
    execvp(cmd[0], cmd);

    /*
     * if execvp returns in this text, an error occured.
     */

    perror("execvp");

    exit(1);
}

static void
dup_and_exec(int fd, int *pp, char *const cmd[])
{
    if (dup2(pp[fd], fd) == -1) {
        perror("dup2");
        exit(1);
    }

    do_close(pp[0]);
    do_close(pp[1]);

    do_execvp(cmd);
}

int
main(void)
{
    char *const ls_cmd[] = { "ls", 0 };
    char *const wc_cmd[] = { "wc", 0 };

    int fds[2];

    int w_stat;
    pid_t ls_pid, wc_pid, w_pid;

    /* create a single pipe to connect our writer and reader processes */

    if (pipe(fds) == -1) {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* create the writer process: ls */

    ls_pid = fork();

    if (ls_pid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (ls_pid == 0) {
        /* this is the child - do the "ls" command */

        dup_and_exec(1, fds, ls_cmd);   /* no return from here */
    }

    /* create the reader process: wc */

    wc_pid = fork();

    if (wc_pid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (wc_pid == 0) {
        /* this is the child - do the "wc" command */

        dup_and_exec(0, fds, wc_cmd);   /* no return from here */
    }

    /* parent process */

    /*
     * It's important to close the pipe completely in the parent,
     * so (in particular) there's no process that could be an
     * additional writer to the "write" side of the pipe.
     *
     * We need to arrange things so that our reader process (the "wc"
     * process in this example) will see EOF when the only writer (the
     * "ls" process) closes its output and exits.
     *
     * If this parent process does not close the write side of the pipe,
     * it remains open, since it's shared across fork(2), so the reader
     * (wc) won't ever see EOF and exit, and this parent process won't
     * ever see the wc exit, and everything hangs.
     *
     * The core problems will have started with the parent, which all
     * children know to be true.
     *
     * The next lines also close the "read" side of the pipe, which
     * is a bit cleaner, but won't affect proper operation of this
     * sample program. But closing all un-needed file descriptors is
     * good hygiene: for longer running applications, or for library
     * code that could be called from longer running programs, avoiding
     * any leaks of file descriptors is a good thing.
     */

    do_close(fds[0]);
    do_close(fds[1]);

    while ((w_pid = wait(&w_stat)) > 0) {
        printf("%s process exited", w_pid == ls_pid ? "ls" : "wc");
        if (WIFEXITED(w_stat)) {
            printf(" (status %d)", WEXITSTATUS(w_stat));
        }
        fputs("\n", stdout);
    }

    if (w_pid == -1 && errno != ECHILD) {
        perror("wait");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

A major problem is here:

```
close(pip[0][1]);
close(pip[0][0]);

...

dup2(pip[0][0],STDIN_FILENO);
close(pip[0][1]);
```

Here you first close the file descriptors, then later in the program you try to use them again.

Comment: But If i comment the close then the program is not ending and I donot see any output

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems in your code:

---

You're making a grandchild of the initial process

```
pid=fork();
char *host = "armadillo";
printf("%s%% ", host);
p = parse();
c=p->head;  
printf("1 \n");
pid=fork(); // this fork here is wrong
```

You are forking and then forking again so the parent make a child and then both of them are making a child each one. **At this point you already have 4 processes**.

Your code would be something like this in that part:

```
pid_t pid;
pid=fork();
char *host = "armadillo";
printf("%s%% ", host);
p = parse();
c=p->head;  
printf("1 \n");
// pid=fork(); // it'll be in another part

if (pid == -1) {
    // print error
    exit(1);
} else if (pid == 0) {
    //child
    close(pip[0][0]);
    close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    dup2(pip[0][1],STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(pip[0][1]); // I added this
    execvp(c->args[0],c->args);
}
//parent
waitpid(pid,NULL,0); // it's not a good idea but I leave it here
printf("2 \n");

// now you can fork again and use the same pid variable
pid=fork();
```

---

You're waiting for the child to finish.

```
if(pid==0)
{
    close(pip[0][0]);
    close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    dup2(pip[0][1],STDOUT_FILENO);
    execvp(c->args[0],c->args);
}
else
{
    waitpid(pid,NULL,0); // you have more commands to execute yet, so you must do it before this
}
```

Waitpid wouldn't be necessary at all if you use the parent process to execute the last command on the pipe (`wc`). But it's up to you if you want to have a parent process. If so, you have to call the `waitpid` once all the children are making his tasks.

---

You mustn't close the pipe *before dup2*..
The error you posted seems to be because of this.

```
wc: standard input: Bad file descriptor 0 0 0 wc: -: Bad file descriptor
```

*After dup2*, you must close the pipe in the child.

```
close(pip[0][0]); // it's ok
close(STDOUT_FILENO); // it's ok but not necessary
dup2(pip[0][1],STDOUT_FILENO);
// here you have to close(pip[0][1]) due to you have already duped it in STDOUT_FILENO
execvp(c->args[0],c->args);
```

If you're going to have a parent, you have to close it just once both children have dupped it.

```
printf("2 \n");

close(pip[0][1]); 
close(pip[0][0]); // You're closing the file descriptor which wc needs to read.
```

---

You're not checking all the possible return status of some functions.

```
pipe
fork
execvp
dup2
```

---

There are something else to improve

```
int pip[3][2];  // in your case with `int pip[2]` would be enough
pipe(pip[0]);
pipe(pip[1]);  // in your case you have to create just one pipe
```

Comment: actually i got the answer.

I removed the 2 close statements in the middle and when I used a different pid variable for the second pid it worked.
So the issue was with the second waitpid which was waiting for a wrong pid value